# Mapping my fcb1010 to the same notes as my Akai APC mini so that it can perform the same functions, hands free

Tags: midi, ableton-live

I'm using an Akai APC mini (without the control surface) to perform some functions on Ableton. Mostly starting and stopping tracks or Looper on different channels.

I also own a Behringer FCB1010 which I would like to use to control some of the loopers so that I can start, stop, record while hands free.

The issue I'm having is finding the right value to put on the FCB1010. I thought I could see what value the APC mini is sending and then set my FCB1010 to output the same signal, but I'm struggling.

Here's some Midi signal conversions:
https://www.inspiredacoustics.com/en/MIDI_note_numbers_and_center_frequencies

Ableton is showing me this, and I don't understand what the actual note/number it is that is mapped:

[image: My looper Ableton mappings]

Is there a better view to see midi mappings? Somewhere where I can press a note and Ableton will show me all the information it is receiving.. so I can match notes on different controllers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. My solution was to download an app called Midi Monitor for my Mac. Now I can make sure the signals are matching in both places.

Comment: As a side note can I ask what you're using to program your FCB1010? Are you doing it manually or using an app to do a sysex dump or something? I have one sitting in a closet mostly because it takes up too much floor space. I occasionally think about pulling it out to control Live but then I remember it being such a pain to program manually via the pedals.

Comment: Hey, I'm programming by bashing the buttons in the correct order. I downloaded some tools which didn't really work for me and I only needed one lot of configuration (so 10 buttons).

Comment: Next time you stop in, please accept the answer for this, to make clear the solution was found.